# libnetcdf.so.4 error while installing qgis 1.6.0

Tags: qgis

I am trying to install Quantum GIS 1.6.0 from source on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit OS. I have GRASS GIS 6.4.1svn installed on the machine. When I run 'make' I get the following error:

```
[ 34%] Built target qgis_analysis
Linking CXX executable qgis
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnetcdf.so.4, needed by /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_inq_vartype'
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_put_att_double'
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_strerror'
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_get_vara_uchar'
.
.
.
.
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_inq_varname'
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `nc_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/app/qgis] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/app/CMakeFiles/qgis.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not able to solve it. Tried installing libnetcdf-dev and libnetcdf6 packages but it was of no help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that you actually have a file called libnetcdf.so.4. http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libnetcdf.so.4 suggests some places to download it from if you don't have it. 
The next step is to make sure the linker (ld) can find the shared library, either use -L/path/to/lib with the compiler or modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.